# Broken glass closet door

Tags: closet, sliding-glass-door

I am new homeowner, so need some basic information. I have glass doors for closet in my kids room. The glass is cracked, and thus I want to fix it. I am wondering if this is something that I can do myself or do I need help. I am ok with not having glass anymore and can replace the doors completely (I guess home depot should have ready made ones). Need suggestions on how to fix it and if it is a small enough project to do myself.

Thanks

Comment: If the glass cracked, it is not tempered glass. Having  regular glass panel the size of a closet door in a  child's room is a potential disaster. I would recommend replacement with a new door.

Comment: yup, I am worried about the same. Want to replace completely.